# Wrong query with the right result

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a query which lookslike the one bellow. The query should query for records in `example` where the `value` equals `3`. The comparisson is `value = '3 value'` where I would expect `value = 3`.

Why results `value = '3 value'` in the same records returned as `value = 3`?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    test.example
WHERE
    value = '3 value';
```

`value` is of the type `INT` and i would expect to get an error or at least the wrong result. Though, i get the right result(depending on how you define 'right') (the result where the value is 3).

Data in the table (id, name, value):

```
1   Example 1   1
2   Example 2   2
3   Example 3   3
4   Example 4   3
5   Example 5   2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

then

```
select "3 value" = 3
```

it returns `1` because

```
select CAST("3 value" AS SIGNED)
```

returns `3`

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the warnings outputted by the query, you would see something as follows:

```
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                     |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '3 value' |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
```

MySQL will truncate the value leaving just the integer.